# Windows 10 Mobile (UWP) NFC credit card reader

Tags: paypal, nfc, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile, hce

My name is Konstantin.

I have the following problem. I'm currently working on one very serious application for bank. This is Universal Windows Platform application but I'm targeting the Windows 10 Mobile. I wanna create an application, which will allow to read information from credit card (basic info that is available in every credit card: holder name, card number, expire date). Can I handle this without using HCE (Host Card Emulation) that is available with Windows 10 mobile preview. If it is, how can I do this?

And one more question, if I have to use HCE, can I use my Nokia Lumia 930 like a device for debugging. I read somewhere, that NL930 does not support HCE, but then why NL730/830 does?

P.S: Sorry for mistakes. English is not my native language :)

Comment: Can you please clarify: do you want to read information from contactless credit cards? (not from a phone emulating a credit card)

Comment: Actually yes. I don't to emulate credit card. I need to read information from them.

Comment: Then you don't need to use HCE at all - that's for emulating cards. You need to focus on using the phone in reader mode. (Not writing an actual answer because I don't know how to do it in Windows)

Answer (score -2):

I think you are referring to NFC enterprise provisioner.
-Implement an NFC HCE (Host Card Emulation) tap+pay application
-Communicate with a smart card or NFC tag

you can refer to this blog: [NFC Team Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nfc/2015/05/01/how-to-write-an-nfc-host-card-emulation-hce-app-with-windows-10-for-mobile/).

```
var taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
```

taskBuilder.Name = bgTaskName;
taskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new SmartCardTrigger(SmartCardTriggerType.EmulatorHostApplicationActivated));
bgTask = taskBuilder.Register();